# Deploying 'old-fashioned' Java web application in Equinox' Jetty

Tags: jetty, osgi, equinox

I'd like to deploy regular war (not OSGi-ed) in Equinox' Jetty. Doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OSGi Web Container specification (part of the OSGi Enterprise Spec) allows you to do exactly this. You will need an implementation of the spec, and there are two available I believe: in Eclipse Gemini or Apache Aries.

Note that deploying a plain WAR to OSGi generally means you don't get any of the advantages of OSGi such as the ability to modularise your web application into bundles. However it is a useful transitional step.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to read about [Pax WAR Extender](http://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/WAR+Extender) since this is what will be putting the war into Jetty. I find that it's best to do the bare minimum to OSGI-fy the war since it should not make the war unusable in a normal app server.

As the link mentions, read this for how to run a WAR with no modification. http://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxurl/War+Protocol.

Or this to run a WAR with minor modification http://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/OSGi-fy+your+WAR.